# CSS property transition fails

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have `div` elements with multiple classes in my webpage. The multiple classes are just to be able to easily manipulate in jQuery based on the nature of the div.

I am expanding and collapsing the div on button click event. Which works fine, but for some reason transition is not working.

I have created a Fiddle for it, please [Click here](https://jsfiddle.net/qvgLLe5k/5/) to check out the fiddle.

I have seen examples of `transition`, my question is should transition be always on top level identifiers? 
such as `div` or `element-id`.

My Css kind of looks like this (also available in fiddle)

```
.display{
  background-color: #a17917;
} /* DIV */
.mytable td div.data-div{
    min-height:120px;
    max-height:140px;
    min-width:120px;
    max-width:140px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    overflow:hidden;
    position: relative;
    transition: height 3s, width 3s;
}
.mytable td div.collapse{
   min-height:120px;
    max-height:140px;
    min-width:120px;
    max-width:140px;
}
.mytable td div.expand{
    min-height:300px;
    max-height:300px;
    min-width:300px;
    max-width:300px;
}
```

On button click, I just add the expand class to div and remove the collapse class (after checking if the div is already expanded or not).

Comment: I see, so can I use transition for min-height? Or I should actually use `height` property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a transition for `height` and `width` but you never change those properties. Easiest thing I can see is to transition `all` properties

```
transition: all 3s;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qvgLLe5k/6/

Comment: Great thanks for the answer. Just for learning purpose, can I use min-height in `transition` as value?

Comment: @progrAmmar Can't see why not. The only thing you can't transition (which is a massive pain) is `height: auto`. If you need that, search StackOverflow for other answers

Answer (score 1):

try this one:

```
.display{
  background-color: #a17917;
}
.mytable td div.data-div{
    min-height:120px;
    max-height:140px;
    min-width:120px;
    max-width:140px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    overflow:hidden;
    position: relative;
    transition: all 3s;
}
.mytable td div.collapse{
   min-height:120px;
    max-height:140px;
    min-width:120px;
    max-width:140px;
}
.mytable td div.expand{
    min-height:300px;
    max-height:300px;
    min-width:300px;
    max-width:300px;
}
```

[**DEMO HERE**](https://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/qvgLLe5k/8/)

Answer (score 0):

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/qvgLLe5k/7/)

```
.mytable td div.data-div{
    min-height:120px;
    max-height:140px;
    min-width:120px;
    max-width:140px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    overflow:hidden;
    position: relative;
    transition: all 3s ease /* change this */
}
```